# Script with IF statment for updating an Oracle table field

Tags: oracle, if-statement

I need your help for creating my script for updating a field in my table.

In my application, I have persons (table PERSON) who create REQUESTS (table REQUEST). 
A person is active when she has created a request during the last 3 years.
I have created a field (ACTIVE - default value: 1) in the table PERSON in order to know if the person is still active.

I create a query for retrieving the number of requests for each person (active request, inactive request):

```
select p.ID, p.LASTNAME || ' ' ||  p.FIRSTNAME personName,p.COMPANY, p.ACTIVE,
(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM request req WHERE req.PERSONID = p.ID) AS "NB_REQUEST", 
(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM request reqAct WHERE reqAct.PERSONID = p.ID and reqAct.requestdate > ADD_MONTHS(TRUNC(SYSDATE, 'YYYY'), -36)) AS "NB_ACTIVE_REQUESTS", 
(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM request reqInact WHERE reqInact.PERSONID = p.ID and reqInact.requestdate < ADD_MONTHS(TRUNC(SYSDATE, 'YYYY'), -36)) AS "NB_INACTIVE_REQUESTS"
from person p
```

This script is working. Now I would like to implement a script for updating the field ACTIVE when the person is active. I tried in a first time to implement the IF Statement but it's not working.

```
select p.ID, p.LASTNAME || ' ' ||  p.FIRSTNAME personName,p.COMPANY, p.ACTIVE,
(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM request req WHERE req.PERSONID = p.ID) AS "NB_REQUEST", 
(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM request reqAct WHERE reqAct.PERSONID = p.ID and reqAct.requestdate > ADD_MONTHS(TRUNC(SYSDATE, 'YYYY'), -36)) AS "NB_ACTIVE_REQUESTS", 
(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM request reqInact WHERE reqInact.PERSONID = p.ID and reqInact.requestdate < ADD_MONTHS(TRUNC(SYSDATE, 'YYYY'), -36)) AS "NB_INACTIVE_REQUESTS"
(IF((SELECT COUNT(*) FROM request reqReAct WHERE reqAct.PERSONID = p.ID and reqReAct.requestdate > ADD_MONTHS(TRUNC(SYSDATE, 'YYYY'), -36))) > 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0) AS "RE-ACTIVE" 
from person p
```

Could you please help me to do that ?

Thanks for your help

Comment: in a query you can use `case` not if . .. ,case when ..count(1) >0... end

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a `CASE ... END` expression. You might also want to try to use `EXISTS` instead of getting the count. That may be faster.

```
SELECT p.id,
       p.lastname || ' ' ||  p.firstname personname,
       p.company,
       p.active,
       (SELECT count(*)
               FROM request req
               WHERE req.personid = p.id) nb_request,
       (SELECT count(*)
               FROM request reqact
               WHERE reqact.personid = p.id
                     AND reqact.requestdate > add_months(trunc(sysdate, 'YYYY'), -36)) nb_active_requests,
       (SELECT count(*)
               FROM request reqinact
               WHERE reqinact.personid = p.id
                     AND reqinact.requestdate < add_months(trunc(sysdate, 'YYYY'), -36)) nb_inactive_requests,
       CASE
         WHEN EXISTS (SELECT *
                             FROM request reqreact
                             WHERE reqact.personid = p.id
                                   AND reqreact.requestdate > add_months(trunc(sysdate, 'YYYY'), -36)) THEN
           1
         ELSE
           0
       END re_active
       FROM person p;
```

An alternative would be Oracle's proprietary `decode()`.

BTW: Looking at your both subqueries comparing `requestdate`, there are only the operators `<` and `>` used. That leaves a gap for the `=` case. Maybe that wasn't intended and you want to check whether to use `=<` or `=<` for one of them.

Comment: Thank you it's working. Could you tell me please if I can do the update of the field ACTIVATE (value = 0 when nb_active_requests = 0) directly in the query ?

Answer (score 0):

Well just replace if statement with case condition

```
select p.ID,
       p.LASTNAME || ' ' || p.FIRSTNAME personName,
       p.COMPANY,
       p.ACTIVE,
       (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM request req WHERE req.PERSONID = p.ID) AS "NB_REQUEST",
       (SELECT COUNT(*)
          FROM request reqAct
         WHERE reqAct.PERSONID = p.ID
           and reqAct.requestdate > ADD_MONTHS(TRUNC(SYSDATE, 'YYYY'), -36)) AS "NB_ACTIVE_REQUESTS",
       (SELECT COUNT(*)
          FROM request reqInact
         WHERE reqInact.PERSONID = p.ID
           and reqInact.requestdate <
               ADD_MONTHS(TRUNC(SYSDATE, 'YYYY'), -36)) AS "NB_INACTIVE_REQUESTS",
                             case when ( SELECT COUNT(*)
                                                                                         FROM request reqReAct
                                                                                        WHERE reqAct.PERSONID = p.ID
                                                                                          and reqReAct.requestdate >
                                                                                              ADD_MONTHS(TRUNC(SYSDATE,
                                                                                                               'YYYY'),
                                                                                                         -36))) >0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 end ) AS "RE-ACTIVE"


  from person p
```